# I need command to overlay video at specied time

Tags: ffmpeg

I have two video, one length video (main) and other 6 second length (bg). I want to overlay bg over main after every 20 second.

I try some ways but after bg run, video stop or if it can run it show bg only one time and no more loop.

```
ffmpeg -y -i "{input}.*" -stream_loop -1 -i bg.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v]scale=1280:720[v0];[1:v]scale=1280:720[v1];[v0][v1]overlay=enable='lt(mod(t,20),6)':shortest=1" -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -b:v 3000k -acodec libmp3lame -b:a 128k -ar 44100 -r 20 -ac 2 -threads 0 -shortest -preset superfast "{output}.mp4"
```

Please help me.

Thank you.

Comment: The best way to do this is to create a new bg.mp4 which is 20 sec long.Then use overlay with `enable='lt(mod(t,20),6)'`

Comment: Thank you. I did as you guide but bg run only first 6 second, after 20 second it only play as a picture, no more play as video.

Comment: Add -stream_loop -1 before the new bg input. And also add shortest=1 to the overlay.

Comment: It is perfect. Thanks.